# como borrar un documento en firestore desde react js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

Buenas estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto con firebase y firestore, pero no logro poder eliminar documentos de firestore. Puedo añadir y ver los documentos que agregue, pero no borrarlos. Adjunto foto de como esta mi base de datos.

[image: firestore del proyecto]

*funcion para borrar*

```
  const borrarServicio = async (id) => {
    const updatedServices = services.filter((service) => service.id !== id);
    setServices(updatedServices);

    const borrarFirestore = async (service) => {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "Servicios", service.id));
    };

    borrarFirestore();
  };

return (
    <div className="peluqueria">
      <h2 className="subtitulos">{categoria}</h2>
      <ServicioForm onSubmit={agregarServicio} />
      <div>
        {services.map((service) => (
          <ServicioSolo
            key={service.id}
            id={service.id}
            texto={service.servicio}
            precio={service.precio}
            agregarServicio={agregarServicio}
            borrarServicio={borrarServicio}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

si cambio manualmente el `service.id` por el id del documento se borra exitosamente, osea que la funcion funciona. Al ejecutar mi codigo me tira este error `ServiciosLista.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

Espero que me puedan ayudar. muchas gracias!!

Copmponente ServicioSolo :

```
const ServicioSolo = ({ texto, precio, id, borrarServicio }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ol className=" list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
          <div className="ms-2 me-auto">
            <div className="fw-bold">{texto}</div>
          </div>
          <span className="badge bg-dark rounded-pill precios">{precio}</span>
          <span
            className="badge bg-warning rounded-pill eliminar "
            onClick={() => borrarServicio(id)}
          >
            Eliminar
          </span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServicioSolo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás sea este parte del error o la total causa:

```
const borrarServicio = async (id) => {

    const updatedServices = services.filter((service) => service.id !== id);

    setServices(updatedServices);

    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "Servicios", id));

};
```

La funcion borrarServicio es una funcion asincrona que recibe el id del documento a borrar, en dicha función ocurre lo siguiente:

- Filtras todos los documentos cuyo id sea distinto al que deseas eliminar.
- El resultado lo asignas al estado que almacena los servicios
- Luego tienes otra función asincrona para eliminar el documento en firebase (esto lo puedes hacer directamente empleando el await y pasando el id que recibe la función principal

**Pero si tu función `borrarServicio` no está recibiendo ese id, debes revisar que esta pasando en el componente `ServicioSolo`.
Si llegas a colocar ese componente en la pregunta y esta respuesta no es de ayuda realizare la actualización necesaria.

Comment: recien le agruegue el codigo del componente a la pregunta

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar. El problema principalmente estaba en la funcion que es para agregar servicios, ya que no estaba agregando el id a cada servicio. Por esto la funcion para borrar no estaba recibiendo ningun id. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Me hizo fijarme de si estaba recibiendo id o no. La marcare como valida!